# Passing a user defined type in a function argument

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have a `type` defined like this:

```
export type KlassConstructor = new (...args: any[]) => Klass;
```

And a constructor in a some another class B like this:

```
constructor(name: string, options?: any, construct?: KlassConstructor) {
  //
  if(construct)
  {
    (this.attr).state = new (construct)();
  }
  //
}
```

I need to initialise B passing the `construct` parameter that does some initialisation. I want to know how can I pass the `args` defined in the exported type to initialise the class `Klass`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried doing `new KlassContructor(args)` but it was giving me this error:

> `KlassConstructor` only refers to a type but is being used as a value
>   here.

I figured out the way to initialise `B` using the type defined by referring to the doc [here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-2.html). `B` can be initialised by just doing `new B(Klass)` or if you want to extend class `Klass` then by doing:

```
let construct: KlassConstructor = class extends Klass {
    public _tag: string;
    constructor(...args: any[], tag: string) {
        super(args);
        this._tag = tag;
    }
};

var b = new B(construct);
```

Answer (score 0):

Class B expects the 'construct' param to be an instance of KlassConstructor.

So before invoking B's constructor, you could create an instance of KlassConstructor. Then ass that into B's constructor method.

Like this:

```
KlassConstructor k = new KlassConstructor(1,2,3);
B b = new B('name', {}, k);
```

I believe you can also do it on the go, like:

```
B b = new B('name', {}, new KlassConstructor(1,2,3));
```

Also, I'm not sure if it applies, but if one class inherits from the other, you can make use of the super() function:

https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/classes.html

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively you can pass args and then initialize your KClass

```
constructor(name: string, options?: any,...args: any[]) {
 KlassConstructor k = new KlassConstructor(args);
}
```